# Does 'rm files*' remove all matches from all sub-directories?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to remove any file that looks like `wordpress-891.sql` from the current directory (not inside sub-directories).

Will `rm wordpress-*.sql` do the trick or will it also remove matches from sub-directories?

Comment: As an aside, while all the other answers end up correct, there is one more twist: it is actually bash, not the rm command, that expands the wildcard. If you have ten matching files in your directory, rm will not see the wildcard, but rather ten individual arguments. If you want rm to do the expansion, you have to enclose your argument in single quotes. For rm, it doesn't make a difference, but in some other contexts it may. Usually, when the wildcard refers to something other than files, such as apt-get packages.

Comment: @KevinKeane, `rm` doesn't do filename expansion... `rm "foo*"` would try to remove a file with a literal asterisk in the name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. Normal globbing `*` is not recursive and neither is `rm`.

If a directory name matches, it won't be removed - you need the `-r` flag to delete a directory.

So it's safe to do that if you're sure you want to delete those files.

You can also make `rm` interactive

```
rm -i wordpress-*.sql
```

then it will ask for confirmation before deleting each file

Answer (score 14):

Yes it does the trick for you and removes all files with that schema in the current directory.
And NO, it does not removes files within the sub-directories.

When ever you are not sure what happens when you run a command like:

```
rm wordpress-*.sql
```

then just run it using `ls`:

```
ls wordpress-*.sql
```

the files you see in output are the ones which will get removed.

When you are trying to get a list like: `foo*`, it is better to use `-d` switch with `ls` to prevent listing files withing a directory named `foobar/` etc.

```
ls -d foo*
```

This trick works for commands which are not used to do the job recursively.

The other thing you can do is to type your desired input, e.g: `wordpress-*` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>, and now all the matches are typed automatically in front of your command.

Comment: My favourite method: `printf "%s\n" wordpress-*.sql`

Comment: You can also pretend Echo like `echo rm file*`. Especially look for hostile filenames like `-rf`

Comment: @eckes: You can cover those more safely with either `rm ./*` or `rm -- *`.

Comment: Yes, or use `xargs -0` @DavidFoerster

Comment: if you go `ls foo*` and you have a directory called `foobar`, you also get a listing of the contents of that directory, so plain `ls` isn't really the best way to what the `rm` will hit

Comment: @ilkkachu Good point, I updated the answer to fix it ;)

Answer (score 12):

No, `rm` does not recurse through subdirectories.

See [Delete matching files in all subdirectories - SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/112078/443564) for methods for deleting files in subdirectories.

If you're ever concerned about accidentally deleting something important, use `gvfs-trash` (which sends files to the trash) instead of `rm` (which permanently deletes files).

Comment: Thanks for the `gvfs-trash` mention learnt something today hardly use it...

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to find and delete all matching files such as `wordpress-*.sql`, you can use `find` command. :)

For instance, you would like to remove all matching files with `wordpress-*.sql` under `test_dir`, do like the following.

```
cd test_dir
find . -name "wordpress-*.sql" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Whenever `find` program really finds a matching file, it tries to execute a command following after `-exec` option. In this case `rm -f {}` will be executed and `{}` will be changed to the match file name.
E.g.

```
rm -f wordpress-169.sql
```

You can also set the depth of sub-directories with `-maxdepth` option.

```
cd test_dir
find . -maxdepth 3 -name "wordpress-*.sql" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Please note that you must specify `-maxdepth` option before other options.
Otherwise you may meet the results what you really don't want to see.

Comment: OP wants the opposite: not to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: GNU find: "the options affect all tests, including tests specified before the option", the list of options below includes `-maxdepth`. Use `-exec rm -f {} +` rather than `-exec \;`, or better yet, just `-delete`